# How to put facebook profile picture into a coordinates of a picture?

Tags: php, facebook, coordinates, photo

I have extracted the user's facebook profile photo.

My question is:
How is it possible that upon clicking a button, the user's facebook profile photo will be in the coords="4,25,33,54"? How to echo the picture into this coordinates?

Thank you all for the time and effort.

Comment: I did.. but i dont know how to. ): Very very weak at this..

Answer (score 0):

You could use CSS to [clip](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/clip) the image when it’s displayed. The image has to be absolutely positioned to do that, and the bottom and right coordinates have to be computed, from the upper left corner of the image.